# UISegmentedControl Changed Event misfires when adding a method inside

Tags: iphone, uisegmentedcontrol

Here is my code for the `UIControlEventValueChanged` event for a `UISegmentedControl`:

```
- (void)segmentAction:(id)sender{

    if([sender selectedSegmentIndex] == 0){     
        pendingIsShowing = YES;
        [freeCutsTable reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }else if([sender selectedSegmentIndex] == 1){
        pendingIsShowing = NO;
        [self showAvailableCuts:sender];
        [freeCutsTable reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

My problem is when the value is changed, the `[self showAvailableCuts:sender]` is called, but the segment control no longer changes its index. If I comment out the method call, it works fine...What I tried to do was pass in the segmented control into `[self showAvailableCuts:sender]` and change it that way, but to no avail...

```
- (void)showAvailableCuts:(id)sender{
    if(!pendingIsShowing){
        NSString *path =@"https://WebserviceURL";       
        NSString* escapedUrl = [path stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        //[sender setSelectedIndex:1];
        NSLog(@"%@", escapedUrl);
        [self parseXMLFileAtURL:escapedUrl];
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why this is occurring...

Comment: What `[self showAvailableCuts:sender];` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking at the code for `[self showAvailableCuts:sender];` all I can think of is - why do you need to pass the 'sender' object itself? Just modify the showAvailableCuts method so that you need to pass only the required value(s) like `[sender titleForSegmentAtIndex:]` , `[sender selectedSegmentIndex]` etc.

ok, firstly the setter should be `[sender setSelectedSegmentIndex:index]` not what you have commented out. I have myself successfully used this -

```
sender.selectedSegmentIndex = index; //in your case index is 1
```

Comment: But the segment is not changing, which is why I was testing to see if setting it inside the showAvailableCuts function would help, but it doesn't